# Display age of an Issue in JIRA dashboard

Tags: jira

I am trying to display the age of an issue that is not yet closed in JIRA dashboard.
i.e. current date-issue created date.
Display the duration in days for every unresolved issue. Is it possible

Answer (score -1):

If you go to your board settings under card layout there is a small toggle to show days in column.

Maybe that will help a bit, even if it is not the total lifetime?